# How to make DotTrace track async/await properly?

Tags: .net, async-await, profiling, dottrace

I'm trying to profile a large .NET 6 solution for a specific use case and user action.

However, I'm seeing a lot of time spent on the following methods rather than neatly broken out async calls as detailed in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Analyzing_Async_Calls.html

- `LowLevelLifoSemaphore.WaitForSignal()`
- `PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()`
- `WaitHandle.WaitOneNoCheck()`
- `LowLevelSpinWaiter.Wait()`
- `SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeout()`
- a lot of `MoveNext()` at a plentitude of locations

None of which lead me to anywhere useful of what is causing these waits and continuations, they all just point at .NET-internal runtime stuff.

I'm using timeline profiling.

I tried debug and release builds and the checkbox at *Collect TPL events* is checked. *Collect profiling data from start* or manually clicking *Start* makes no difference either.

What else can I try to get more useful profiling data?

Comment: Ensure your profiler is up-to-date and that you're doing a timeline snapshot. If these are correct and it's still not working, then ask JetBrains.